# hasAttribute XML function to check Attribute availability

Tags: xml, vbscript, attributes

Below is the snippet from my XML code that I'm trying to parse using VBScript.

```xml
<detailFilters>
  <detailFilter>
    <filterExpression>[Rank]<=10</filterExpression>
  </detailFilter>
</detailFilters>
<summaryFilters>
  <summaryFilter use="prohibited">
    <filterExpression>[Rank]<=10</filterExpression>
  </summaryFilter>
</summaryFilters>
```

Elements `<DetailFilter> and <SummaryFilter>` may or may not have "use" attribute. When I'm trying to check the existence of this attribute using the below logic

```vb
For k = 0 To qryNodes(j).getElementsByTagName("filterExpression").Length - 1
  flterStatus = qryNodes(j).getElementsByTagName("detailFilter")(k).hasAttribute("use")
```

I get the error

> object doesnt support this property or method

If I change `hasAttribute` to `getAttribute` like this:

```vb
flterStatus = qryNodes(j).getElementsByTagName("detailFilter")(k).getAttribute("use")
```

I'm getting a different error:

> Invalid use of null

Please let me know how I can find existence/availabilty of an attribute.

Comment: Where does the XML come from, and how do you fill `qryNodes` with it? An XMLDOM object should produce different errors than what you showed.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers for the edit & making the question more understandable. Its a  code from an appl.

qryNodes is xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/dcc:report/dcc:queries/dcc:query"), where dcc is the NameSpace. 

I have managed to fix 'Invalid use of null' issue by using VarType function to check whether flterStatus is null. If its a null, I'm assigning a string value as below,

If VarType(flterStatus) = 1 Then  
Excel Cell Value = "Enabled" 
else 
Excel Cell Value=flterStatus
End If

This may not be a very efficient way of solving the issue.However, it is giving the expected result.